# CSS Image Hover Effect?

Tags: html, css

I want my image hovers to look like [this](https://www.medi360.in/NewHome/Our_Specialists.html),
but For some reason, my CSS styling is not working. You may notice the `#content` in each of the CSS styling options. That is because I only wanted these styles to apply to a certain section of my website. I looked online and used the W3Schools resource, yet for some reason, it still doesn’t work. My images do not have the hover effect.

```css
#content.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

#content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#content .column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content .row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#content .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#content .img:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#content.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="team">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="/static/img/team/team-1.jpg" alt="" style="width: 200px;">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="team-prof">
        <a href="#">Dr. Pawan Kumar Kesari</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show HTML as well. I noticed that some tags don't have space between selectors: `#content.container`, `#content.text`. Other possibility - don't use float to make a column layout. Use flexbox instead.

Comment: I added HTML for the first image I used. All of the other images are copies of this one. Thanks!

Comment: Check your selectors for example `#content.text`. Change float to flexbox layout.

Comment: Ok, I am learning about flexbox right now

Comment: _“I looked online and used the W3Schools resource”_ — that’s where your mistake is! Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide) instead! (Excuse the little joke). At any rate, what’s your desired result?

Comment: I want my image hover to work like this: https://www.medi360.in/NewHome/Our_Specialists.html

Comment: It appears you haven't really followed the guide very well (you've added a bunch of irrelevant divs etc) if this is the guide you are referring to; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade

Comment: You also have NOT identified what ``#content`` is, so the CSS will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't followed [THIS guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp) very well.

You also have not identified what `#content` is.

You need to revise how you target IDs, Classes and Elements in CSS.

Here is your code remodified to follow the guide, plus I added in `#content` for you.

```css
#content .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

#content img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#content .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#content .img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#content .text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">


<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="team">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="team-prof">
        <a href="#">Dr. Pawan Kumar Kesari</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate you helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

There were flaws in your code. There was no shared container. There were no spaces in the css rules between the identifier and the classes. `#content .overlay` had a `height: 0` - this makes the object invisible. My answer isn't perfect, but I've tidied up the code a bit.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
}

.main_content_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main_content_box_image {
  position: relative;
}

.main_content_box:hover > .main_content_box_image p {
  display: flex;
}

.main_content_box:hover > .main_content_box_image img {
  filter: brightness(25%);
}

.main_content_box:hover a {
  color: #337ab7;
}

.main_content_box_image img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 125px; /* or 50%*/
  transition: .5s;
}

.main_content_box_image p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.main_content_box a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="main_content_box">
      <div class="main_content_box_image">
        <img src="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/11/01/13/20191101130724350/pwa_vertical_1024_f1555b2890fcb39f7ecc85cf65e73fc5.png" alt="">
        <p>MBBS, General Physician</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Dr. Pawan Kumar Kesari</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content_box">
      <div class="main_content_box_image">
        <img src="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/11/01/13/20191101130724350/pwa_vertical_1024_f1555b2890fcb39f7ecc85cf65e73fc5.png" alt="">
        <p>MBBS MD(Medicine) General Physician</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Dr. Nitin Kumar Srivastava</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content_box">
      <div class="main_content_box_image">
         <img src="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/11/01/13/20191101130724350/pwa_vertical_1024_f1555b2890fcb39f7ecc85cf65e73fc5.png" alt="">
         <p>MBBS General Consultant and Diabetician</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Dr. (Mrs) Halima</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a block of code isn’t really a useful answer. Please [edit] it and explain how this post answers the question.

Comment: Yes I agree. I tried this code to see if this would fix my problem, but unfortunately, it did not.

Comment: Judging by the content of the code you provided, it is very DIFFICULT to judge what the result should be. The html structure in your question is broken - the main container was missing. I just cleaned up the code.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. My main goal is for the image hover to work like this: https://www.medi360.in/NewHome/Our_Specialists.html

Comment: Hey sergey, I was wondering if you had any more input by chance. If not, that is ok as well.

Comment: Hello. Yes, of course there is. I promised to help you, and I will help you. I just have a lot of work to do at the moment. As soon as I am free, I will do it for you.

Comment: I will do with a break. Those. a lot of work. If you see an incomplete result, don't be intimidated. I will tell you how I will do it completely.

Comment: I did as I promised. I apologize for the delay in answering due to the large amount of work I have. Please appreciate my work. I did everything as you wanted. The hover is working correctly - i.e. when you hover the mouse cursor over the photo, the hover of the lower header is triggered, when you hover over the lower header, the animation of the main hover is triggered. Hope I cater to your needs.